# лицензия на лицензирование невозможна без license

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

предлагаю сделать метки [лицензия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%8f) и [license](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/license) синонимами для [лицензирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

или хотя бы метку [license](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/license) сделать синонимом для [лицензия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%8f).

---

единственное приходящее в голову применение для меток [лицензия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%8f)/[license](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/license) в отрыве от метки [лицензнирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) — это в вопросах типа «я купил „супер-пупер-прогу лицензия” и у мине по ей вопросик». но эти метки в подобных вопросах явно не несут полезной нагрузки.

Comment: Я бы ещё предложил использовать заглавные буквы в сообщениях.

Comment: [Были же когда-то славные времена.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/456425/176217)

Comment: Давно их добавил на синонимизацию, так и висят. Спасибо за то что поднял вопрос.

Comment: @älёxölüt, весьма странно. такое ощущение, что очистилась история правок (ну, не я же своими руками написал в вопросе заглавные буквы!). может быть, пользователь, внёсший правку, был удалён, и история правок пропала?

Comment: Ну, может это были не руки.

Comment: @älёxölüt, вспомнил: движок не позволял опубликовать вопрос. так что: **меня вынудили!**

Answer (score 4):

[license](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/license) → [лицензирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

[лицензия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%8f) → [лицензирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

сделать [license](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/license) и [лицензия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%8f) синонимами для [лицензирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

[license](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/license) → [лицензия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%8f)

сделать [license](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/license) синонимом для [лицензия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score -1):

ничего не менять, и так всё хорошо.